# Do the lip balms we use have to be halal?

Tags: halal-haram, cosmetics

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

I would like to know, does our lip balms have to be halal in order for us to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walikum AsSalam wa Rahmatulliahibarakatuh,
Check this answer in the link below(though I must mention that the answer refers to lip stick and not lip balms)
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/26799/using-lipstick

This is the most revelant part from the link that answers your question about lip balm-

"It is also subject to the condition that it does not contain any substance that may harm the body or '***that is impure such as pig fat.***' In that case it is haraam, because we are forbidden to do things that will harm us, as the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “there should be no harming or reciprocating harm.” "
Basing on this, lip balms should be made from halal ingredients. And Allah knows the best.